# Subtracting a finite ring

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For the finite ring $R_2 = \{00000000,00000001..,11111111\}$ find:

$ 11010111 - 10101010 = N_2 =$___________

I am trying to answer this question. I cannot subtract normally in assembly so, using the formula, i get:

```
(11010111 + ~10101010) mod (1000000) = ?
```

which i believe equates to:

```
100101101 mod 1000000 = ?
```

I am now stuck on solving this part. Can anyone help me solve this or if familiar with this type of question, let me know if i am doing it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is $R_2$ ? Why is $00000000$ not just $0$ ?

Comment: I believe because it is a byte ring = 8 bits. This is new to me as well so i am not positive.

Comment: You need to define your ring operations.  One ring on your numbers uses addition and multiplication $\bmod {256}$.  Another uses bitwise operations.  There are others.  Maybe $R_2$ defines it, but not for me.